# Disable click link or button in a webview Android

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview load URL "http://www.google.com"..I want disable event when we click link or button in that webview..I set clickable="false" but not work..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a custom `WebViewClient` and override  `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` & `shouldOverrideKeyEvent`. For example:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent (WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
         // Do something with the event here
         return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.google.com")) {
             // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
             return false;
        }

        // reject anything other
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       return true;
    }  
});
```

Comment: Provided code might help, but in order to make it a good answer you should also describe/explain why/how exactly does your code solve the problem.

Comment: It disables the touch completely so. It is not the correct sol.

Comment: Javascript can also be used to unbind or disable all click events from page. Which is working for me now.

Answer (score 4):

No idea to disable HTML Native button in webview but you can disable link

```
public class formatHTML {
    public static String changeHTMLFormat(String htmlObject){
        String result = "", CSSCoding = "";

        CSSCoding = htmlObject;
        CSSCoding = CSSCoding.replaceAll("<[aA].*?>", "<u>");
        CSSCoding = CSSCoding.replaceAll("</[aA]>", "</u>");
        return CSSCoding;
    }     
}
```