# Android - WebView disable navigation to other page

Tags: android, button, webview, navigation

How to prevent navigation to another page when click on a link or button inside a WebView page, (I do not want to disable touch listener).

Comment: Here, is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19552580/4856761

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set `new WebViewClient()` into webview and catch link in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` method
Like this

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
if(url.contains(youUrl)){
    //do something  
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, this is the condition i was looking for..Thanks.

Comment: return true to block navigation, return false to continue to the passed url