# Is it possible to freeze the android webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I need feature in my app, there is a button call 'freeze' and when it clicked I want to freeze the webview. What mean by freeze the webview is that after it froze the webview shouldn't navigate to any other page, for example if the user clicked on a link or submit a form, it should not do anything.

I tried to block requests using the `WebViewClient` methods `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and `shouldInterceptRequest`. But it's not working, is there any other way I can achieve this?

```kotlin
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?
    ): Boolean {

        if (!isFroze) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?
    ): WebResourceResponse? {
        if (!isFroze) {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, I need to capture the clicked element. If the user clicked on a link I want to capture that event using JavaScript interface.

Comment: You can try returning consumed i.e true from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.. have look at [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426742/dont-navigate-to-other-pages-in-webview-disable-links-and-references).

Comment: Yeah, I did that and it's working for links and form, but not javascript page loading. for example youtube after I clicked the freeze button when I click on a video its switching to that page which mean its loading the video.

Comment: thanks, in that link, I found a JavaScript version of the solution that's working for me. I am posting that as answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

As ADM commented when I return `true` on `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` solved the link and form submit, but not the JavaScript page loading like in YouTube. So to solve that I need to execute a small snippet JavaScript which is `stopPropagation`

```kotlin
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        view?.evaluateJavascript("""
            (function () {
                document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }, true);
            })()
        """.trimIndent()) {}
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
    }

    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?
    ): Boolean {

        if (!isFreeze) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
        }
        return true
    }
}
```