# Don't allow Webview to open hyperlinks

Tags: android, html, webview

I have the following code that allows you to load html code into a Webview:

```
val html = description.html ?: ""
val encodedHtml = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(html.toByteArray(), android.util.Base64.NO_PADDING)
descriptionWebView?.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64")
```

Also here is the code of my custom descriptionWebView:

```
open class CustomFrameWebView : WebView {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(getFixedContext(context)) {
        setupView()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(getFixedContext(context), attrs) {
        setupView()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(getFixedContext(context), attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        setupView()
    }

    override fun setOverScrollMode(mode: Int) {
        runCatching {
            super.setOverScrollMode(mode)
        }.onFailure {
            Timber.e(it)
        }
    }

    private fun setupView() {
        this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
        setThemeMode(context, this.settings)
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can open any links that come to me in `description.html`.

**Q**: How can I prohibit clicking(redirect) on these links? I found a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19552580), but I'm not sure if it applies to my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following code to solve my problem:

```
descriptionWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

Official documentation [info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)).

> If a WebViewClient is provided, returning true causes the current
> WebView to abort loading the URL, while returning false causes the
> WebView to continue loading the URL as usual.