# how to display privacy policy in the android app as per current google policy? with in the app or as web link?

Tags: android, privacy

I have a question, do I need to display the privacy policy in the app itself in text form(in the activity) or I can display it as a link to my website so that google accepts the app in play-store listing.

I am very confused, did not find any specific direction from anywhere.

Currently, it's displayed in 2 places.
1st- After installation user will see the pop-up and link to the website. If the user accepts, a pop-up will be shown next time.

2nd- In the menu, there is also a link to the website.

Comment: correction:----> If the user accepts, a pop-up will not be shown next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can show your website's privacy policy in a webview inside your app. That way it's easy to manage and update.

You can use something like this to stop user from navigate to other pages from inside of your app or you can simply remove links from your privacy policy page

[Android - WebView disable navigation to other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731821/android-webview-disable-navigation-to-other-page)
[Disable click link or button in a webview Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526676/disable-click-link-or-button-in-a-webview-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can display it using any of the two options:

1.) In activity (text form) - this is certainly allowed and technically possible, the only issue is if your privacy policy gets updated you'd need to release a new build.

2.) Webview - As per the google play's policies :

"the privacy policy should be publicly available"
so you'll any ways end up hosting it somewhere on the web.

Better to use the same web URL in an android webview, so if the content/text of the priv policy changes in future, you'd just need to update the web URL and won't need a new release at all.
This will automatically satisfy Google play policies as well.